# rpy2 cannot load R library ggplot2 on Mac

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, rpy2

I have installed rpy2 and R on my Mac, both are latest version. Also have installed R `ggplot2` through R studio. Now I'm trying `rpy2`, hoping to run R code in IPython terminal.

My code is super simple, but got error when trying to load `ggplot2`.

Here's the code in IPython:

```
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
%R require(ggplot2)
```

I have also tried `%R install.packages("ggplot2")` before require this library.
But always got run time error like this:

> /Users/abc/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/**init**.py:185: RRuntimeWarning: Loading required package: ggplot2
>      warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)

I'm using Mac, installed rpy2 through Conda.
Is there anyway to solve this problem, so that ggplot2 or any other required R libraries can be loaded in IPython?

Later I have also tried with python 3, but it's a windows machine, and got this type of error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The anaconda path suggests that you are using Python 2.7. `rpy2` has opted to no longer support Python for several years already. Whatever version you are using is not longer supported, and you'll be lucky if it is working at all with recent versions of R.

Upgrade to Python 3.

Also, versions of `rpy2` on conda tends be outdated or very outdated. Try installing `rpy2` from pypi (using `pip` for example).

Comment: It seems that I'm not sure how to add screenshot here. So just added in the question above. I did try python3, on my windows 10, but will get errors like "The system %s is not supported". I have edited R_HOME, R_user in my environment variable, still got the same error...

Comment: Yes, there is a bug in `situation.py` to report in plain text that Windows is not supported. In order to hope have it supported, the community of Windows users will have to get the source (from Github or Bitbucket), remove that check, and figure out what remains to be finished for the Windows to work.